# Conditional regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

I'm trying to make a regex which can match a phone number and so tell me if the phone number is either valid or not.

I would like to verify if there is a country id before the phone number, this one is well formated.

For example : **+(33)0123456789** I want to be sure if the user start to type the first parenthesis it must be followed by number and ended by a closing parenthesis.

I have succeeded with PCRE engine

```
^[+]?((\()?(?(2)[0-9]{1,4})(?(2)\)))?([0-9]{2}){1}([\.\- ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$
```

But I realized this way doesn't work with javascript engine, conditional is not supported.

```
^[+]?((\()?((?=\2)[0-9]{1,4})((?=\2)\)))?([0-9]{2}){1}([\.\- ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$
```

It doesn't fill my needs. I want to check if the first parenthesis is set then it must be followed by number and a closing parenthesis.

So I ask you if there is a workaround in javascript to do this ?

Some help would be really appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: It sounds as if you just want to make `(\d{1,4})` optional. Try `^\+?((?:\([0-9]{1,4})\))?([0-9]{2})([. -]?[0-9]{2}){4}$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtO1Eh/1).

Comment: Exactly what I want to do ! It seems that conditional regex is not what I need for this case. I stubbornly tried to use it but your workaround is much more simplen thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `((\()?(?(2)[0-9]{1,4})(?(2)\)))?` part of the regex is matching an optional sequence of  smaller patterns. `(\()?` matches an optional `(` and places it in Group 2. Then, `(?(2)[0-9]{1,4})` matches 1 to 4 digits if Group 2 matched. Then `(?(2)\))` matches `)` if Group 2 matched. Basically, this is equal to `(?:\([0-9]{1,4})\))?`.

Thus, you need no conditional construct here.

You may use

```
^\+?(?:\([0-9]{1,4})\)?[0-9]{2}(?:[. -]?[0-9]{2}){4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtO1Eh/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\+?` - an optional `+`
- `(?:\([0-9]{1,4})\)?` - an optional sequence: `(`, 1 to 4 digits and `)`
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `(?:[. -]?[0-9]{2}){4}` - 4 occurrences of an optional space, dot or `-` followed with 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.